# atualização do Xcode - perda de todos simuladores

Tags: ios, xcode

Estava com a versão 7 do Xcode e acabei de fazer o update para a versão 8.2.1 e todos os simuladores de iOS sumiram.

Existe alguma maneira de eu fazer com que eles apareçam novamente no Xcode sem precisar fazer o download de todos novamente?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que eles desaparecem pois do Xcode 8 para cima só da para fazer projeto para iOS 8+, mas caso não seja isso é só clickar na opção "Add additional simulators" perto do botão "Run" que vai abrir uma lista com os Simuladores disponíveis.

Comment: ou seja, vou ter que baixar todos os simuladores?

Comment: Se o simulador que vc quiser for iOS 8+ então sim, vai ter que baixar os que for usar, agora se for iOS menor que o 8 so com o Xcode 7 mesmo.